# Shifting viewport in webGL canvas

Tags: webgl

I'm making a game where the user uses WASD keys to move the viewport to see the game world. As of right now, only the initial sprites in viewport are being rendered. I was able to move the viewport via gl.viewport(x, y, width, height) by updating its x and y, but when I move to the viewport to different world space, the screen is black and there should be sprites. No errors in the log and updates are being computed. I cleared the screen each drawing and

```
private drawSprite( webGL : WebGLRenderingContext,
    viewport : Viewport, 
    sprite : AnimatedSprite) : void {

        let canvasWidth : number = webGL.canvas.width;
        let canvasHeight : number = webGL.canvas.height;
        let spriteType : AnimatedSpriteType = sprite.getSpriteType();
        let texture : WebGLGameTexture = spriteType.getSpriteSheetTexture();

        let spriteWidth : number = spriteType.getSpriteWidth();
        let spriteHeight : number = spriteType.getSpriteHeight();
        let spriteXInPixels : number = sprite.getPosition().getX() + (spriteWidth/2);
        let spriteYInPixels : number = sprite.getPosition().getY() + (spriteHeight/2);
        let spriteXTranslate : number = (spriteXInPixels - (canvasWidth/2))/(canvasWidth/2);
        let spriteYTranslate : number = (spriteYInPixels - (canvasHeight/2))/(canvasHeight/2);
        this.meshTranslate.setX(spriteXTranslate);
        this.meshTranslate.setY(-spriteYTranslate);

        let defaultWidth : number = canvasWidth;
        let defaultHeight : number = canvasHeight;
        let scaleX : number = 2*spriteWidth/defaultWidth;
        let scaleY : number = 2*spriteHeight/defaultHeight;
        this.meshScale.set(scaleX, scaleY, 0.0, 0.0);//1.0, 1.0);

        let rotation: Vector3 = sprite.getRotation()
        this.meshRotate.setThetaZ(rotation.getThetaZ())

        MathUtilities.identity(this.meshTransform);
        MathUtilities.model(this.meshTransform, this.meshTranslate, this.meshRotate, this.meshScale);

        // FIGURE OUT THE TEXTURE COORDINATE FACTOR AND SHIFT
        let texCoordFactorX : number = spriteWidth/texture.width;
        let texCoordFactorY : number = spriteHeight/texture.height;
        let spriteLeft : number = sprite.getLeft();
        let spriteTop : number = sprite.getTop();
        let texCoordShiftX : number = spriteLeft/texture.width;
        let texCoordShiftY : number = spriteTop/texture.height;

        webGL.bindBuffer(webGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexDataBuffer);
        webGL.bindTexture(webGL.TEXTURE_2D, texture.webGLTexture);

        let a_PositionLocation : GLuint = this.webGLAttributeLocations.get(this.A_POSITION);
        webGL.vertexAttribPointer(a_PositionLocation, this.FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE_COORDINATE, webGL.FLOAT, false, this.TOTAL_BYTES, this.VERTEX_POSITION_OFFSET);
        webGL.enableVertexAttribArray(a_PositionLocation);
        let a_TexCoordLocation : GLuint = this.webGLAttributeLocations.get(this.A_TEX_COORD);
        webGL.vertexAttribPointer(a_TexCoordLocation, this.FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE_COORDINATE, webGL.FLOAT, false, this.TOTAL_BYTES, this.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_OFFSET);
        webGL.enableVertexAttribArray(a_TexCoordLocation);

        let u_MeshTransformLocation : WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_MESH_TRANSFORM);
        webGL.uniformMatrix4fv(u_MeshTransformLocation, false, this.meshTransform.getData());
        let u_SamplerLocation : WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_SAMPLER);
        webGL.uniform1i(u_SamplerLocation, texture.webGLTextureId);
        let u_TexCoordFactorLocation : WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_TEX_COORD_FACTOR);
        webGL.uniform2f(u_TexCoordFactorLocation, texCoordFactorX, texCoordFactorY);
        let u_TexCoordShiftLocation : WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_TEX_COORD_SHIFT);
        webGL.uniform2f(u_TexCoordShiftLocation, texCoordShiftX, texCoordShiftY);

        webGL.drawArrays(webGL.TRIANGLE_STRIP, this.INDEX_OF_FIRST_VERTEX, this.NUM_VERTICES);
}
```

The vertex shader

```
uniform mat4 u_MeshTransform;
uniform vec2 u_TexCoordFactor;
uniform vec2 u_TexCoordShift;
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;
varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
void main() {
    gl_Position = u_MeshTransform * a_Position;
    vec2 tempTexCoord = a_TexCoord * u_TexCoordFactor;
    v_TexCoord = tempTexCoord + u_TexCoordShift;
}
```

FragShader

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_Sampler;
varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Sampler, v_TexCoord);
}
```

Any idea why the moving viewport wouldn't render the sprites in that space. I'm positive all the values are updated. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

`gl.viewport` only sets the conversion from normalized device coordinates to pixel space. It won't help you move the view around.

If you want to move the view around you usually add in a view matrix either in your math in Javascript where you compute `meshTransform` or else by adding another matrix to your shader

```
gl_Position = u_viewProjectionTransform * u_MeshTransform * a_Position;
```

or

```
gl_Position = u_projectionTransform * u_viewTransform * u_MeshTranform * a_Position;
```

You then set `u_projectionTransform`  for your projection ([perspective](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html) or [orthographic](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html)) and you set `u_viewTransform` for your [camera](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html)